# Grouping of strings

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I have a list of possible groups for a list of strings. Each string consists of several words, which are the string elements.  I want to group the strings according to these elements.

Each group is based on a common word: all strings in the group must contain that word -- although I don't require that all strings containing that word be in the same group.  A string with **N** words can be in any of **N** different groups.  Each string may be in only one group.  Each group must have at least two strings.

Goal: form the groups to maximize the quantity of strings that are in a group (minimize "orphan" strings).

For instance, if I have the following list of strings:

```
cycle cost
pump cost
cycle analysis
cost example
```

I would have all possible words of each string as potential groups. I now want to group these strings so that all, or as many as possible, get into a group.

I have tried the naive approach to take the group with the most strings in it first, which in this example would be `cost`, but this leaves `cycle analysis` without a group.

The result I'm looking for in this example is:

```
cycle: cycle cost, cycle analysis
cost: pump cost, cost example
```

Does there exist an algorithm for this sort of problem already? Any pointers on the approach to take would be helpful.

Comment: That was truly a mouthful. It all depends on how the strings and groups are associated. Can you elaborate, and if it helps, provide a simple example.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want ?

Comment: I have added an example to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Looks related to the set cover problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like @m69 has a good lead.  Your problem has a couple of modifications:

- Remove all sets of size 1;
- When a set is (tentatively) added to the solution, all elements
  of that set must be removed from all remaining sets

  - ... and any sets with fewer than two elements get removed.

Unfortunately, this is NP-hard, at *best*.  If the application's input is not ridiculously large, I'd use a brute-force heuristic with liberal backtracking.

Initialization:

- A *viable* set is one with at least 2 elements.
- Process your list.

  - Place all viable sets into a list ***S***.
  - Place all elements into the universe, ***U***.

Process:

1. Pick a set ***P*** from ***S***; add it to the solution list.
2. Remove all elements of ***P*** from each remaining set in ***S***.
3. Remove all non-viable sets from ***S***.
4. If ***S*** is empty

   - Then If all elements of ***U*** exist in ***S***,

     - Then stop and report solution.
     - Else return to previous call level
   - Else [***S*** not empty]
     Recur on this process with the new ***S***
5. If recursion reported success,

   - Then return to previous call level.
   - Else go back to step 1, and choose the next set from ***S***

You can gain some advantages in this by judicious ordering of the sets in ***S***.  I recommend a greedy algorithm, with value measured according to the *desirability* of its element in the sets of ***S***.  For instance, an element that appears in *only* one set would shove that set to the top of the list.

Does that get you started?

Comment: for bigger problems (and depending on setup) I'd formulate this as an MIP (with some random cost function) and let a solver do the magic for me.